# CupertinoTabBar and BottomNavigationBarItem UI not updating with ChangeNotifierProvider

Tags: flutter, flutter-provider, flutter-state, flutter-cupertino

I'm using Flutter [`Provider`](https://pub.dev/packages/provider) package for managing `currentIndex` state of `CupertionTabBar`. I'm doing this instead of using `setState` of `StatefulWidget` because I want to programmatically update current active tab from within the tab view pages.

Here's the app code:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const App());
}

class App extends StatelessWidget {
  const App({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return CupertinoApp(
      theme: const CupertinoThemeData(
        brightness: Brightness.light,
      ),
      home: ChangeNotifierProvider(
        create: (context) => AppState(),
        child: const TabsPage(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class TabsPage extends StatelessWidget {
  const TabsPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Consumer<AppState>(
      builder: (context, appState, child) {
        return CupertinoTabScaffold(
          tabBar: CupertinoTabBar(
            backgroundColor: CupertinoColors.white,
            currentIndex: appState.currentTabIndex,
            onTap: (index) => appState.currentTabIndex = index,
            items: const [
              BottomNavigationBarItem(
                icon: Icon(CupertinoIcons.house),
                activeIcon: Icon(CupertinoIcons.house_fill),
              ),
              BottomNavigationBarItem(
                icon: Icon(CupertinoIcons.play_rectangle),
                activeIcon: Icon(CupertinoIcons.play_rectangle_fill),
              ),
              BottomNavigationBarItem(
                icon: Icon(CupertinoIcons.heart),
                activeIcon: Icon(CupertinoIcons.heart_fill),
              ),
              BottomNavigationBarItem(
                icon: Icon(CupertinoIcons.music_albums),
                activeIcon: Icon(CupertinoIcons.music_albums_fill),
              ),
              BottomNavigationBarItem(
                icon: Icon(CupertinoIcons.ellipsis_circle),
                activeIcon: Icon(CupertinoIcons.ellipsis_circle_fill),
              ),
            ],
          ),
          tabBuilder: (context, index) {
            return const TabPage();
          },
        );
      },
    );
  }
}

class TabPage extends StatelessWidget {
  const TabPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return CupertinoTabView(
      builder: (context) => Consumer<AppState>(
        builder: (context, appState, child) => Center(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              Text('Current Tab: ${appState.currentTabIndex}'),
              const SizedBox(height: 8.0),
              ...List.generate(
                5,
                    (index) => Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                  child: CupertinoButton.filled(
                    child: Text('Go to tab $index'),
                    onPressed: () => appState.currentTabIndex = index,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class AppState extends ChangeNotifier {
  int _currentTabIndex = 0;

  int get currentTabIndex => _currentTabIndex;

  set currentTabIndex(int index) {
    _currentTabIndex = index;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

Checkout the live code with results on [DartPad](https://dartpad.dev/?id=47e6bfc2b212f43f6d39b5fe39fbb35b).

As you can see although `AppState.currentTabIndex` is updating and reflected in `Text` widget but current active `BottomNavigationBarItem` UI is not updating.

Your help is appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried using CupertinoTabView's `routes:`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the [docs](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/cupertino/CupertinoTabScaffold/tabBar.html) of `CupertinoTabScaffold` `tabBar` property:

> The CupertinoTabBar.currentIndex is only used to initialize a
> CupertinoTabController when no controller is provided. Subsequently
> providing a different CupertinoTabBar.currentIndex does not affect the
> scaffold or the tab bar's active tab index. To programmatically change
> the active tab index, use a CupertinoTabController.
>
> If CupertinoTabBar.onTap is provided, it will still be called.
> CupertinoTabScaffold automatically also listen to the
> CupertinoTabBar's onTap to change the controller's index and change
> the actively displayed tab in CupertinoTabScaffold's own main content
> area.

So, holding instance of `CupertinoTabController` in `AppState` and updating `index` on it works:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const App());
}

class App extends StatelessWidget {
  const App({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return CupertinoApp(
      theme: const CupertinoThemeData(
        brightness: Brightness.light,
      ),
      home: ChangeNotifierProvider(
        create: (context) => AppState(),
        child: const TabsPage(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class TabsPage extends StatelessWidget {
  const TabsPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final appState = Provider.of<AppState>(context, listen: false);
    return CupertinoTabScaffold(
      controller: appState.tabController,
      tabBar: CupertinoTabBar(
        backgroundColor: CupertinoColors.white,
        items: const [
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(CupertinoIcons.house),
            activeIcon: Icon(CupertinoIcons.house_fill),
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(CupertinoIcons.play_rectangle),
            activeIcon: Icon(CupertinoIcons.play_rectangle_fill),
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(CupertinoIcons.heart),
            activeIcon: Icon(CupertinoIcons.heart_fill),
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(CupertinoIcons.music_albums),
            activeIcon: Icon(CupertinoIcons.music_albums_fill),
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(CupertinoIcons.ellipsis_circle),
            activeIcon: Icon(CupertinoIcons.ellipsis_circle_fill),
          ),
        ],
      ),
      tabBuilder: (context, index) {
        return const TabPage();
      },
    );
  }
}

class TabPage extends StatelessWidget {
  const TabPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return CupertinoTabView(
      builder: (context) {
        final appState = Provider.of<AppState>(context, listen: false);
        return Center(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              Text('Current Tab: ${appState.tabController.index}'),
              const SizedBox(height: 8.0),
              ...List.generate(
                5,
                (index) => Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                  child: CupertinoButton.filled(
                    child: Text('Go to tab $index'),
                    onPressed: () => appState.tabController.index = index,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}

class AppState extends ChangeNotifier {
  final tabController = CupertinoTabController();

  @override
  void dispose() {
    tabController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }
}
```